i was trying to create an array and apply reduce to find the facotrial, but why the loop isn't stopping on the condition
I tried to create an array in js using for loop but it the loop isn't stopping at the desired number. can somebody explain why it's happening. when I am entering number 7 the loop is running upto 70.
this is the code having for loop, after putting index=1 and index>a+1 it doesn't stop on a+1 condition

the output after I entered 7


Your code should be posted here as text.

Welcome to stackoverflow. Please have a read of the [ask] section of the [help]. I would also recommend you take the [tour]. As @Pointy pointed out, you cannot post screens of code/errors on SO. Please refer to [mre].

The input received is string. The + operator, when used with a string, performs string concatenation instead of addition. So "7" + 1 results in "71", not 8 .
Just add parseInt()
let a = parseInt(prompt('Enter factorial number'), 10);
let b = [];
for (let index = 0; index <= a; index++) {
    b.unshift(index);
    console.log(b);
}


Now I get it, I had assumed that JS had typecasted the 1 into an integer automatically. Thank you for your Help
